# How can a date that's stored in a SQL Server Express database correctly sometimes display as 01 Jan 0001?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, iis-6, windows-server-2003

This is for a newspaper website we run - it's quite busy (approx 2 million page views a month) - so don't know if traffic is a significant issue here or not.

But every few days it would seem an entirely random collection of their latest stories show dates as Monday, January 1, 0001 when formatted like:

```
this.NewsStory.DatePublished.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy")
```

But looking at the data via SQL Server Management tools, it's stored entirely correctly.  And if I refresh the application pool for this website the dates all go back to being correct.

Any ideas what's happening? More of an iis problem than SQL or .net?  Really lost with this, when it happens seems entirely random, and what stories it effects also seems to be random.

It's a Windows 2003 Server running iis 6.  The website is coded in C# and the data is in a SQL Server 2005 Express database.

Thank you for any suggestions you may have.

More code as requested - here's the .net code calling the stored procedure:

```
public static DataTable GetNewsStoryByURL(string url)
{
   DataTable table = NewsStoryData.GetDataTableTemplate();

   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FangleConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetNewsStoryByURL", con);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@url", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
   cmd.Parameters[0].Size = 512;
   cmd.Parameters[0].Value = url;

   try
   {
      con.Open();
      SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
      table.Load(reader);
      reader.Close();
      con.Close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
         con.Close();

      throw ex;
   }

   return table;
}
```

And here's the stored procedure itself:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetNewsStoryByURL]
( @url nvarchar(512) )
as
  select        
    dbo.fangle_News.[Identifier] as Identifier,
dbo.fangle_News.[GUID] as GUID,
dbo.fangle_News.[URL] as URL,
dbo.fangle_News.PageTitle as PageTitle,
dbo.fangle_News.MetaKeywords as MetaKeywords,
dbo.fangle_News.MetaDescription as MetaDescription,
dbo.fangle_News.NewsHeader as NewsHeader,
dbo.fangle_News.NewsAbstract as NewsAbstract,
dbo.fangle_News.NewsContent as NewsContent,
dbo.fangle_News.ImageUrl as ImageUrl,
dbo.fangle_News.ImageCaption as ImageCaption,
dbo.fangle_News.Image_W as Image_W,
dbo.fangle_News.Image_H as Image_H,
dbo.fangle_News.DateCreated as DateCreated,
dbo.fangle_News.DatePublished as DatePublished,
dbo.fangle_News.DateLastModified as DateLastModified,
dbo.fangle_News.CreatedBy as CreatedBy,
dbo.fangle_News.AuthoredBy as AuthoredBy,
dbo.fangle_News.LastModifiedBy as LastModifiedBy,
dbo.fangle_News.[Status] as Status,
dbo.fangle_News.Tags as Tags,
dbo.fangle_News.Priority as Priority,
dbo.fangle_News.Version as Version,
dbo.fangle_News.SendToTwitter as SendToTwitter,
dbo.fangle_News.TwitterText as TwitterText,
dbo.fangle_News.PicturePurchaseURL as PicturePurchaseURL
 from       
    dbo.fangle_News with (nolock)
 where      
    dbo.fangle_News.[URL] = @url
    and dbo.fangle_News.[Status] = 2
    and dbo.fangle_News.Version = 1
```

Comment: that seems like `DatePublished` is not filled from the DB correctly sometimes... without any further information it is hard to help... how does `NewsStorey.DatePublished` get its data from the DB ? Do you have any exceptions along the way ?

Comment: The data comes from a stored proceedure using ado.net - it's does it in a few different ways depending on where the date is displayed, but when the problem exists it also exists on the news story page - so this is just a simple get one row based on an ID from the database.  There is a try catch in there, but if that was throwing an expection I wouldn't get any data i.e. the headline etc...which is all showing fine.

Comment: it doesn't matter if it is simple or not - the problem is most probably in the part getting the data from the DB... you need to show much more details (like the SP and/or the .NET source code getting the data and/or the exception handling code), otherwise anything you get will be based on pure speculation IMO

Comment: Have addede the further code above as can't get on with this box auto sumbitted everytime I press return - sorry, new here!

Comment: @dwavell First, I'd say start using the disposable pattern: using(). Second, I wonder if `nolock` is making you read uncommitted records, and the DateCreated filed is getting a default value which is not generated yet because the insert is not committed. I don't know how sql server works internally though.

Comment: @Ingenu would using() make a difference when we're manually closing the reader and the connection anyway? I'm not sure that we could have uncommitted records as pretty much all the news is inserted in one go via a daily data import - once it's run all stories are comitted to the db and only updates are then made, but never to the datepublished field.

Comment: Any more thoughts on this?  Have tried the using() thing, but we won't know if it makes any difference yet as the problem only crops up every few days or so...really don't have much confidence in it making any difference - hope to be proved wrong, but would like some other ideas to try if possible.